# get and return a dynamic amount from some page.cs to class

Tags: asp.net, httpclient

```
public class Paypal//name of class
public string Pay { get; set; }//Field called pay
public Paypal() { }//General constructor
public class Amount//into Paypal class
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "currency_code")]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

now is a method into Paypal class:

```
public static string ConvertToPay()
{
    var request = new OrdersRequest
    {
        Intent = "CAPTURE",
        PurchaseUnits = new PurchaseUnit[]{ new PurchaseUnit{
        Amount = new Amount//New object from above
                {
                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                    Value ="???"//Here I want to get a different amount every time
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
    return jsonContent;
}
```

in page some.cs written

```
Paypal.Amount payamo = new Paypal.Amount();
payamo.Value= SumOfClass.Items[SumOfClass.SelectedIndex].Value;
```

It does not work! How the **Value** will get a variable amount??
I tried several ways, with no success

Comment: What is the `SumOfClass`? What is not working and what are you trying to do? Please provide some explanation.

Comment: SumOfClass is ID of select. and the val in option is Variable amount.  I want to receive and pass it on to the class..How to do it properly?